Filtering table using reactive value in shiny
I'm wrapping my head around this issue and cannot understand how it works. I have several user inputs that are conditional. Firstly the user chooses the criteria type with a radio button, then a select input appears for him to set the actual axis parameter they want. The dropdown menu in select input is a list of column names.
ui<- fluidPage(
            radioButtons("xbkct", h1(class="cch", "Select X-axis criteria"),
                         choices =c("Bookies"="bks", "Team"="tmc"),
                         inline = TRUE
                        ),
            conditionalPanel("input.xbkct==='bks'",
                             selectInput("xbookct1", "Bookies criteria",
                                         choices = NULL)
                            ),
            conditionalPanel("input.xbkct==='tmc'",
                             selectInput("xteamct1", "Team criteria",
                                         choices = NULL)
                            ),         
            radioButtons("ybkct", h1(class="cch","Select Y-axis criteria"),
                         choices = c("Bookies"="bks", "Team"="tmc")
                         ,inline = TRUE
                        ),
            conditionalPanel("input.ybkct==='bks'",
                             selectInput("ybookct1", "Bookies criteria",
                                         choices = NULL)
                            ),                      
            conditionalPanel("input.ybkct==='tmc'",
                             selectInput("yteamct1", "Team criteria",
                                         choices = NULL)
                            )
              mainPanel("Points selected by brushing, with brushedPoints():",
                                  gt_output("plot_brushed_points")
                        )
)

When I try to filter a table depending on my reactive variable xvar() and yvar(), I can’t make it work without calling it and renaming it first in select() before filtering. This only puts back the problem since I need the name of the column in my table which are the xvar() and yvar() value.
server<- function(input, output, session) {
xvar <- reactive({
    if (input$xbkct=='bks')
    {
      input$xbookct1
      } else if (input$xbkct=='tmc')
      { input$xteamct1
        }
    })
  
  yvar <- reactive({
    if (input$ybkct=='bks')
    {
      input$ybookct1
      } else if (input$ybkct=='tmc')
      { input$yteamct1
        }
    })
mytable<- reactive({
  dat<-dft() %>% 
    select(.,x=xvar(),y=yvar(),c(4,8:16,18:19,21:38)) 
  dat<-dat %>% 
  filter(., x >= xmin ,x <= xmax, y >= ymin, y <= ymax) %>% 
        mutate(across(where(is.numeric) & !(c("ODDS1","ODDS2","ODDS3")), ~ round(.x, 3)))
  dat<-gt(dat) %>%
    opt_interactive() %>%
    tab_header(md("**In-depth parameter details**")) %>%
    tab_options(table.width = pct(100),
    container.width = pct(150))
dat

})
output$plot_brushed_points <- render_gt({
mytable()
})
}

I've tried this and it's not throwing any error nor yielding any entry in the table either:
dft() %>%
filter(.,xvar()>=xmin,xvar()<=xmax, yvar()>=ymin, yvar()<=ymax) %>%
…

EDIT : adding the df for reproducible example`
df<-structure(list(YY = c(2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L
), DD = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MM = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Jan", "Jan"), FULLDATE = structure(c(19723, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724), class = "Date"), ID = c("ENG PL", "ENG PL", 
"ESP D1", "ESP D1", "ESP D1", "SCO PL"), Country = c("England", 
"England", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Scotland"), League = c("Premier League", 
"Premier League", "Liga", "Liga", "Liga", "Premiership"), Season = c("2023/2024", 
"2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024", "2023/2024"
), HOME = c("Liverpool", "West Ham", "Getafe", "Real Sociedad", 
"Valencia", "Rangers"), AWAY = c("Newcastle", "Brighton", "Rayo Vallecano", 
"Alaves", "Villarreal", "Kilmarnock"), T1 = c(4, 0, 0, 1, 3, 
3), T2 = c(2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1), FSCORE = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Home", "Away", "Draw", "Upcoming"), class = "factor"), 
    ODDS1 = c(1.45, 2.3, 2.4, 1.54, 2.3, 1.19), ODDS2 = c(4.9, 
    3.65, 3, 3.9, 3.4, 5.8), ODDS3 = c(6.25, 2.85, 3.25, 6.5, 
    3, 11), OUTCOME = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1), m1 = c(4.2, 2.93333333333333, 
    2.88333333333333, 3.98, 2.9, 5.99666666666667), sd = c(2.47537875889731, 
    0.678847061813877, 0.436844747402705, 2.48096755319371, 0.556776436283002, 
    4.9079561258566), indxcol = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), sp1 = c(-3.45, 
    -1.35, -0.6, -2.36, -1.1, -4.61), sp2 = c(1.35, -0.8, 0.25, 
    2.6, -0.4, 5.2), ovr = c(5.37368050668543, 5.96324044178345, 
    5.76923076923077, 5.96070596070595, 6.2233589087809, 10.3659018466321
    ), wavg = c(0.388888888888889, 0.414772727272727, 0.346820809248555, 
    0.326633165829146, 0.390804597701149, 0.322401334074486), 
    ospr = c(4.31034482758621, 1.58695652173913, 1.35416666666667, 
    4.22077922077922, 1.47826086956522, 9.2436974789916), mosd = c(1.69671004281823, 
    4.32105182203408, 6.60036168564786, 1.60421283820363, 5.20855375877647, 
    1.2218256465404), HTP = c(38, 29, 23, 22, 21, 31), ATP = c(22, 
    26, 16, 14, 17, 25), HLG = c(2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1), ALG = c(1, 
    4, 0, 0, 3, 2), HL3G = c(3, 7, 7, 3, 2, 5), AL3G = c(4, 5, 
    0, 0, 4, 5), HBKS = c(60.6440071556351, 52.0491803278688, 
    48.9795918367347, 48.036253776435, 55.7739557739558, 67.3780487804878
    ), ABKS = c(51.4598540145985, 46.7787114845938, 51.7766497461929, 
    43.1372549019608, 53.7037037037037, 39.8773006134969), HMT = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0), AMT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GDM = c(22, 3, 
    2, 7, 1, 18), GDA = c(2, 8, -8, -6, -7, 5), CHG = c(33, 28, 
    17, 20, 16, 24), CAG = c(25, 32, 11, 12, 23, 17), CHGH = c(19, 
    13, 9, 10, 9, 13), CAGA = c(4, 15, 5, 3, 8, 3), CHPT = c(57.5757575757576, 
    46.4285714285714, 52.9411764705882, 50, 56.25, 54.1666666666667
    ), CAPT = c(16, 46.875, 45.4545454545455, 25, 34.7826086956522, 
    17.6470588235294), MHGH = c(2.375, 1.85714285714286, 1.28571428571429, 
    1.42857142857143, 1.28571428571429, 2.16666666666667), MAGA = c(0.571428571428571, 
    1.875, 0.714285714285714, 0.375, 1.33333333333333, 0.5), 
    MHG = c(1.1875, 0.8125, 0.642857142857143, 0.714285714285714, 
    0.642857142857143, 1), MAG = c(0.25, 0.9375, 0.357142857142857, 
    0.214285714285714, 0.571428571428571, 0.2), MSHH = c(1.75, 
    0.714285714285714, 0.714285714285714, 0.428571428571429, 
    0.857142857142857, 1.66666666666667), MSAA = c(-1.71428571428571, 
    0.25, -0.142857142857143, -1.125, -0.833333333333333, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dft() is a reactive version of df where some parameters are previously fitered by the user.
Thanks for your help

Can you include dft in your code or a minimal example so the problem is reproducible?
